# CSRF tokens - how to implement properly?

Tags: php, security, csrf

I've just setup a simple CSRF protection in my application. It creates a unique crumb which are validated against a session value upon submitting a form.

Unfortunately this means now that I can't keep multiple instances (tabs in the browser) of my application open simultaneously as the CSRF crumbs collide with each other.

Should I create an individual token for each actual form or use a mutual, shared crumb for all my forms?
What are common sense here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do either. It depends on the level of security you want.

The OWASP Enterprise Security API (ESAPI) uses the single token per user session method. That is probably a pretty effective method assuming you have no XSS holes and you have reasonably short session timeouts. If you allow sessions to stay alive for days or weeks, then this is not a good approach.

Personally, I do not find it difficult to use a different token for each instance of each form. I store a structure in the user's session with key-value pairs. The key for each item is the ID of the form, the value is another structure that contain the token and an expiry date for that token. Typically I will only allow a token to live for 10-20 minutes, then it expires. For longer forms I may give it a long expiry time.

If you want to be able to support the same form in multiple browser tabs in the same session, then my method becomes a little trickery but could still be easily done by having unique form IDs.

Comment: You mean, each instance of each form has it's own token? Ie. `<input type="hidden" name="token_form-registration#3" value="secret" />`?

Comment: I think having a single token per session is reasonable as long as you don't submit them over http (only https). They share many security concerns with session ids. If you have XSS, the attacker can open iframes, read the tokens, and do CSRFs anyways.

Comment: If you have XSS, you've already lost. Additional per-form nonces won't save you (attacker will be able to get a new form, with fresh nonce, fill it in and submit, just as the user would). Single value per user is absolutely enough for CSRF.

Answer (score 4):

The [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) has the most definitive answers for this sort of thing.  It discusses different approaches and balancing of security vs. usability.

In brief they recommend having a single token per (browser) session.  In other words in your case the same token is shared among tabs.  The cheat sheet also emphasizes that it is very important not to expose your site to cross site scripting vulnerabilities, as this subverts the per session CSRF token strategy.

Answer (score -3):

As I know about CSRF, you can use

**1) Random number and save it into session:**
Add it to hidden input called hidden, then when you recive info you can check hidden field with the session value

**2) Static config variable**  (like previous but no session)
The hidden field will contain this value (variable from config). When you validate, you will check the hidden posted and the config security key value

**3) HTTP Referer**
You can use http referrer to know where user come from then check it with the real domain(this method can attack if your website contain xss).

As I know you can use any solution :)

Comment: Your 2nd example; How can you suggest using a static variable as a CSRF Token?  The whole idea behind tokens are their uniqueness, meaning that no one should be able to guess in beforehand what the token would be. How on earth would this make any form safer?

Comment: 2 does not work, as the key is not individual per user.
3 is not recommended as a lot of companies firewalls strip out the referer header, and it's really unrealiable.

Comment: HTTP Referer is not a secure way to defeat CSRF.  (Neither is a static variable.)

Comment: @Industrial : i don't mean static variable , i mean variable like config info $csrf = '' ; // please change it to any word you like , and i talk about csrf in admin , so no one able to know the word as it variable and hidden , so when attacker redirect user to add admin he will require the hidden field -> from config , for user captcha can do the jop ,

Comment: i don't mean static in all site the variable can change to any word any time by edit the value of config only , and i told http referrer can make problem if your website contain xss

Comment: Thank you for answer my comment , and the negative 2 :) , i think here you can add your opinion and other can correct your answer or can talk about your answer :) , But Never Mind I Like To talk about security :) regards