# CSRF token generation: Time based or Session based?

Tags: php, forms, security, session

I want to securely process a form data in a php project.

I found that it can be done in either with

1. `current time based tokens` or
2. `session based tokens`

I want maximum security. Which of this strategy is good?

Comment: CSRF token security levels are simple, there's 'Not Using CSRF Tokens' [0%], then there's 'Using CSRF Tokens' [100%], and finally there's stressing out over the security of the security feature [100% + ulcers and hair loss]

Comment: @Sammitch Ah doesn't make sense to me :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466241/new-csrf-token-per-request-or-not

Comment: I think [`mcrypt_create_iv( MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php) based is the best ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use a token based purely on the current time (option 1). If everyone sees the same token, it's trivial for an attacker to request the "current" token himself (e.g., through his own server) and add use it in a CSRF attack.

Option 2 can't be attacked this way, since the attacker would need to be in the same session (however that's implemented) in order to get the right token.